# "I see nothing " vs "I don't see nothing"

Tags: grammar, multiple-negation, polarity-items

As far as I understand, both of these sentences imply that the speaker is unable to see anything.

Is one sentence *more correct* than the other or can they be used interchangeably everywhere?

Also, why doesn't a negative word "don't" have any effect on the resulting meaning of the second sentence in the title?

For eg.

> I see her

and

> I *don't* see her

are pretty different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In standard English (unlike much dialect and slang usage), "I don't see nothing" is incorrect - unless your intended meaning is "I see something".  In standard English, a "double negative" results in one negation cancelling out the other negation, resulting in an affirmative meaning.

In standard English, the correct expressions are:

- I don't see anything.
- I see nothing.

Comment: I think you can use I "don't see nothing" just to have fun, but, put in a formal paper, it should be "I do not see anything" or "I see nothing".

Comment: What about, I see no something VS I don't see something